Unable to render specific content when the url changes
can you update this so that when when the user clicks on the button in View the following occur:

the url is changed so that /chocolates is added
when the url change is registered the View is removed and ChocolateView is displayed

note:
SideNavigator should not re-render.
code::
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _currentView = 'View'; // Default view

  void _navigateToChocolateView() {
    setState(() {
      _currentView = 'ChocolateView';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          const SideNavigator(),
          if (_currentView == 'View')
            View(
              onNavigateToChocolateView: _navigateToChocolateView,
            ),
          if (_currentView == 'ChocolateView') const ChocolateView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SideNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideNavigator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("SideNavigator() Loaded");
    return const Text("SideNavigator");
  }
}

class View extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onNavigateToChocolateView;

  const View({Key? key, required this.onNavigateToChocolateView})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("View() Loaded");

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Text("View"),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            onNavigateToChocolateView();
          },
          child: const Text('Go to Chocolate View'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ChocolateView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChocolateView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

I tried chatgpt/claude all morning and its not working one bit.
i didnt find a similar stackoverflow
here is a video of the feature i am trying to copy::
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Tw54wYHC9U
as you can see the url is changing and the side navigator is not re-rendering/re-loading.
i manipulated the side navigators text to verify that the component is not re-rendering/reloading.
when i check my browsing history i see that new urls have been visited.
I was able to make a side navigator that does not re-render when the content changes but if i touch the url all the components re-render:::


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("MAIN BUILD RELOADED");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Content'),
      ),
      drawer: DrawerComponent(),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          NavigationRailComponent(),
          VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          MainContentComponent(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainContentComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainContentComponentState createState() => _MainContentComponentState();
}

class _MainContentComponentState extends State<MainContentComponent> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: _getPage(_selectedIndex),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getPage(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return Center(
          child: Text('Main Content for Item 1'),
        );
      case 1:
        return Center(
          child: Text('Main Content for Item 2'),
        );
      // Add more cases for additional items
      default:
        return Center(
          child: Text('Main Content'),
        );
    }
  }
}

class NavigationRailComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationRailComponentState createState() => _NavigationRailComponentState();
}

class _NavigationRailComponentState extends State<NavigationRailComponent> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationRail(
      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
      labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
      destinations: [
        NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: Text('Item 1'),
        ),
        NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
          label: Text('Item 2'),
        ),
        // Add more NavigationRailDestinations for additional items
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DrawerComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Item 1'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              _MainContentComponentState()._selectedIndex = 0;
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Item 2'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              _MainContentComponentState()._selectedIndex = 1;
            },
          ),
          // Add more ListTile widgets for additional items
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



What you're asking for is a very simple task to do. Except the last criteria you added. That the SideNavigator() shouldn't be re-rendered. I'm not exactly sure, what you meant by the word re-render. But in Flutter, you can't exactly choose a particular portion to rebuild and skip the rest.

@HippoFish here is a video of how the side navigator should not re-render/reload while having the url change::
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Tw54wYHC9U
i also updted the problem description.
thank you for taking the time to read through the problem

Hey @Juan Casas. Looks like the video you made is showing a webpage. Which wasn't created with Flutter. Different frameworks have different approaches towards things. In web, there's a thing called partial rendering. Which is a great thing for web. But in Flutter you can optimize your rebuilds . But technically we never need partial rendering. But if you still need that kind of behavior. let me show you a small hack.

Hope you're having a happy coding day.
But yeah, as I mentioned in the comment. There's no way to partially refresh the screen. And if some widgets are under a parent widget, and the parent widget rebuilds there's no way to directly choose a specific child to rebuild and stop rebuilding the rest.
But... You caan try this simple hack. That definitely comes with some caviats.
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _currentView = 'View'; // Default view
late final Widget sidebar;
  
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    sidebar = const SideNavigator();
  }
  
  void _navigateToChocolateView() {
    setState(() {
      _currentView = 'ChocolateView';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          sidebar,
          if (_currentView == 'View')
            View(
              onNavigateToChocolateView: _navigateToChocolateView,
            ),
          if (_currentView == 'ChocolateView') const ChocolateView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Caveats
First of all, after the initialization of MyHomePage, that sidebar will have no idea what's happening outside of it. It will be totally isolated.
Now maybe, you'll change theme and so on, but that sidebar won't be able to know about any of the changes outside of it. Which is not usually what we want. SO, that's not a way we will go.
TIP: A small tip would be, don't keep your business logic inside your build() methods. That's like the very first rule when you get into flutter. This will help you not to worry about the rebuild of Sidebar() widget.

Edited!
Btw, it feels like you're trying to achieve web standards, maybe you're trying to build a website with Flutter. Which is almost never suggested. And by changing the path, if you want to change the url shown in your web browser. That is a totally different thing. For that, look up GoRouter. A routing package for flutter. And build two pages. And navigate between them. Routes will change. In your case, you'll also have to understand the topic of subroute.
Good luck brother!


why did some take off a point from my question?

@JuanCasas Nooo. Not at all. Really sorry to hear that brother.

@JuanCasas I just upvoted your question. Hopefully, that helps!
